Variant of Baire theorem
I consider $(X,d)$ a complete metric space. I have this weak form of the Baire theorem : There does not exist nonempty open subset $O$ of $X$ such that $O=\bigcup_{n\geq 0} F_n$ where the $F_n$ are closed subsets  with empty interior.
I would like to prove that it implies this : Any countable collection of closed subsets $F_n$ with empty interior has union $\bigcup_{n\geq 0} F_n$ with empty interior.
I am sure it is simple to prove but I don’t get it.
By contradiction I get that if $\text{int}\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 0} F_n\right)\neq\emptyset$ then I can let $A= \text{int}\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 0} F_n\right)$, it is an open set such that $A\subset\bigcup_{n\geq 0} F_n$ but in this setting I cannot apply the first theorem.
I tried to « complete » $A$ in order to recover an equality instead of an inclusion but it does not work.
Have you some hints please ? (Rather than full answer please)
Thank you a lot

How I would do it, is consider $A$ as a union of countable amount of closed sets. Every open set in a metric space can be written like this.

Actually, you can also give $A$ a metric, and equivalent but different one, which makes it complete. So then, $A$ is a complete metric space which is a union of countable amount of closed sets. This does work.

@Jakobian Thank you for your help, I would like to try the first hint. I need to check if the closed subsets $B_n$  satisfy the empty interior condition in $A=\bigcup_{n}B_n$.

Jakobian's hint about unions of closed sets is good, but as an alternative to making a new metric, you could pick on a particular ball in $A$, and write it as a countable union of closed balls $(B_m)m$. Then, consider $F'{m,n} = B_m \cap F_n$.

@TheoBendit I am trying to make it works with first hint but I plan to look at the second thank you !

@G2MWF That's not what I intended. You want to take $A = \bigcup_{n, m} B_n\cap F_m$, and then $B_n\cap F_m$ is what has an empty interior in $A$. Or see what Theo Bendit wrote, which omits the step with writing $A$ as a union of closed sets.

@Jakobian Thank you a lot. I thought the fact that the union of the $B_n$ equals $A$ was sufficient to ensure that each $B_n$ is included in some $F_m$.
